# Spring webserver how to share file in folder

Tags: java, spring

How can I share file in folder using Spring eg. `/tmp/file.mp4`. that it is accessible from the IP? Like this `10.11.14.122/file.mp4`

Comment: Do you mean share a folder or just one file?

Comment: No, for all files in this folder.

Comment: which web server do you use?

Comment: Spring MVC with REST

Comment: I mean web server: tomcat, jetty, spring-boot or other thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is need `spring-boot` to serve your static files. You just need to configure the path in `Override addResourceHandlers`, full code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TmpApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TmpApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/tmp/**").addResourceLocations("file:///./myfolder/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

There is a document: [boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)